# jQuery select data attribute and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which has an ID, on click of the button I need to match the ID of the button with the documents data-id attribute and then add a class to the respective element.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79pbn821/)

```js
this.$('.add-resource').click(function() {
  var testId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert(testId);
  $('#layoutCanvas').find("[data-id='" + testId + "']").addClass('hidden');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary add-resource" id="567">Button</a>
<div id="layoutCanvas">
  <div data-id="567">
    Test 1
  </div>

  <div data-id="235">
    Test 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.hidden` class is not defined, so the class is added, but no css is applied.

I've only added the `.hidden` class

```js
this.$('.add-resource').click(function () {
     var testId = $(this).attr('id');
     //alert(testId);
     $('#layoutCanvas').find("[data-id='" + testId + "']").addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary add-resource" id="567">Button</button>


<div id="layoutCanvas">
    <div data-id="567">
        Test 1
    </div>
    
    <div data-id="235">
        Test 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well to modify a bit you can use template literals to overcome the dirtiness of string concat,its just a add on

```js
this.$('.add-resource').click(function () {
     var testId = $(this).attr('id');
     //alert(testId);
   $("#layoutCanvas").find(`[data-id='${testId}']`).addClass('hidden')
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<a class="btn btn-primary add-resource" id="567">Button</a>
<div id="layoutCanvas">
    <div data-id="567">
        Test 1
    </div>
    
    <div data-id="235">
        Test 2
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.hidden{
  //attribute you want to add
 
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` method hides the selected elements in jQuery :

```
this.$('.add-resource').click(function () {
     var testId = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(testId);
     $('#layoutCanvas').find("[data-id='" + testId + "']").hide();
});
```